# Heatmap Layer not showing on custom array

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a university project that shows a heatmap based on pollution data collected through an arduino. The steps in doing so are as follows

- Sends the data from the arduino to a phone that adds each record into a firestore collection. 'data'
- The second step is weighting the data within a scale of 1-10 and returning the data back to a separate collection called 'weightage'
- Third step is retrieving the data off this collection and showing it in a google map within the heatmap layer. I used the JavaScript API to do so.(Ionic native did not have visualization lib)

The issue is with the third step. Initially as I was waiting on another teammate to weight the data, I set up the initial map api and a simple example of the heatmap layer with three predefined points functionally.

The intended result is a FAB that allows us to choose different pollutants and display different heatmap layers. Once the weighting was done I was unable to display the any formatted data at all.

I am an amateur at angular and ionic and was only able to get this far through tutorials and i am completely stumped. Any help would be appreciated

Currently I'm trying to create a new array with location and weight. The initial attempts failed and threw many exceptions as it was a normal array and another post i saw on here converted a regular one into an MVCArray. Once i used the MVC Array, i got rid of the errors but the heatmap refused to load any new values inserted into the array. so far i have a 108 objects in the collection and the MVC array but my initial predefined array are the only points that show on the map.

```
import { Injectable, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Dataline } from 'src/app/dataline';


declare var google;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class JSService {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  options;
  map:any;
  collection:AngularFirestoreCollection;
  data;

  heatmapdata: [];




  constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.collection = this.afs.collection<Dataline>('weightage');
      this.data = this.collection.snapshotChanges();
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => {

  }, 3000);

  }
    // we need the data to be populated here using some magick
    // in a JSON format that looks like location: x , weight: x
    // do some magick to make it fit into a nice array and then the
    // result we will plop into the heatmap



 heatmapCO(location,element){
    let latLng= new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.pointArray,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 20,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });
   } 

  heatmapCO2(){

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{
      let newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lon,value.lat);
      let newweight = value.co;
      this.heatmapdata.push({location: newlatlng ,weight: newweight});
    });
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.globalelem.nativeElement, this.options);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.heatmapdata,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });

  }
  heatmapNH4(){

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{
      let newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lon,value.lat);
      let newweight = value.co;
      this.heatmapdata.push({location: newlatlng ,weight: newweight});
    });
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.globalelem.nativeElement, this.options);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.heatmapdata,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });
  }
  heatmapEth(){

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{
      let newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lon,value.lat);
      let newweight = value.co;
      this.heatmapdata.push({location: newlatlng ,weight: newweight});
    });
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.globalelem.nativeElement, this.options);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.heatmapdata,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });
  }
  heatmapAce(){

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{
      let newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lon,value.lat);
      let newweight = value.co;
      this.heatmapdata.push({location: newlatlng ,weight: newweight});
    });
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.globalelem.nativeElement, this.options);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.heatmapdata,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });

  }
  heatmapTol(){

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{
      console.log(value);
      let newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lon,value.lat);
      let newweight = value.co;
      this.heatmapdata.push({location: newlatlng ,weight: newweight});
    });
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.globalelem.nativeElement, this.options);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: this.heatmapdata,
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });
  }

init(location,element){

    let latLng= new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false
    };

    var heatMapData = [
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(25.307711, 55.485403), weight: 6},
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(25.311251, 55.485886), weight: 5}      
    ]; //format of weighted heatmap data (currently showing 3 points on the road outside uni)

    console.log(heatMapData); 

    let pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatMapData);

    this.data.subscribe((value)=>{ // pulling data from firestore and inserting into an MVC array
      for(let x of value){
        pointArray.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(x.payload.doc.data().lon),Number(x.payload.doc.data().lat)), weight: x.payload.doc.data().co});
      }
      console.log(pointArray);
    });

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      dissipating: true,
      maxIntensity: 10,
      radius: 15,
      opacity: 1.0,
      map: this.map
    });

    heatmap.setData(heatMapData);
    console.log("reached after mapload");  
    //  heatmap.setMap(this.map);  // This defines the heatmap we see, if dissipating is set false and radius is low, we see nothing. bump radius up and you'll start seeing the circles
  }
}
```

I'm using ionic 4.12.0, node 11.12.0, angular 7.2.2.
Plugins used are Geolocation, angularfire, chart.js, googlemaps js api

Please ignore the syntax errors in the functions as its still under progress and I'm trying to get basic functionality ready and then move to implementing this functionality within each of the functions.

- Key function is init()

https://github.com/FGButterLettuce/stackoverflowAPM